# How to search for a dapp based on its address?

Tags: contract-invocation, dapps, addresses

There are many websites that track dapps like http://dappradar.com or https://www.dapp.com. Unlike Etherscan one particular dapp doesn’t have to be registered on such specific website in order to be listed.
As a result, many dapps whose source code and/or tag is unknown to Etherscan can be found on such websites. Thus if you have the name of Dapp you can find its contract address

However, there are many times, where I [find the address](https://etherscan.io/address/0x258ab32997cbbe508b5a2af17d16df1139a04474#code) first, but not the website nor the name.
So how to search dapps by addresses instead of by name in order to [find how to gamble on that game](https://etherscan.io/address/0x258ab32997cbbe508b5a2af17d16df1139a04474#code) for example ?

Answer (score -1):

Somethimes the onwner of the contract will publish some information right on etherescan. e.g.
https://etherscan.io/token/0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2

then: `ctrl+f` makerdao.com

However it is not required for someone to post data, and a developer can deploy hundreds of contracts to a chain trying to troubleshoot a problem, so it is going to be very common to find dead end contracts/addresses on-chain.

Comment: Etherscan doesn’t track nor allow to search for ᴅᴀᴘᴘꜱ. As it’s a block explorer, ᴅᴀᴘᴘs listed there is a compulsory process which isn’t the point of the question.

Comment: And the question mentioned, not finding on etherscan.